# API backend's app revision 'X' not the same as expected 'Y'

Tags: java, google-app-engine

All.

After deployment of my Java application to Google-App-Engine standard environment I face with following backend exception:

Request url :

```
/_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs
```

Exception :

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: exception occurred while calling backend method (SystemService.java:398)
com.google.api.server.spi.response.BadRequestException: API backend's app revision '397417657720349940' not the same as expected '397211310482055273'
    at com.google.api.server.spi.BackendService.getApiConfigs(BackendService.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:42)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:363)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:113)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    ...
```

As a result I can't use my newly deployed app to migrate traffic to it.

Did any-one face the same problem? How did you solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue since I tried the [Endpoint v2 Beta API](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/). Do you have tried the new version of Cloud Endpoints then rolled back to the v1?

Comment: I removed my dependencies `jackson-binding` and `jackson-annotations` to use the repackaged one (inside appengine) and it solved my issue.

Comment: Hi, I didn't tried Endpoint V2.

Comment: hi, i am  facing the same issue, is it fixed ?

Comment: Hi, I used API-explorer and it fixed the issue for me. But I wonder if there is any solution for described case.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs once you try to upload a version while another version is still not finished updating or you tried to cancel by using Ctrl+C key.

Solution: rollback the conflicting version by going to your app engine sdk bin folder and run the command which will take your snapshot as a parameter

**On mac** : `mac-bin$ ./appcfg.sh rollback   patth-to-your-snapshot-in-target-folder`

**On Windows** : `win-bin>appcfg.cmd rollback   patth-to-your-snapshot-in-target-folder`

Comment: The thing is that in my situation the new version upload is completed and new version instance started. And even redeployment doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: you need to run rollback anyhow, even version upload is completed but logs show this version mismatch